# How can I use esp-idf-mirf nRF24L01/Si24R1 driver to transmit audio sampled with i2s_read?

Tags: c, audio, esp32, esp-idf, radio-transmission

## Original post - 12/2022

I'm currently trying to transmit audio via nRF24 with an ESP32 development board using a driver [library](https://github.com/nopnop2002/esp-idf-mirf) from [nopnop2002](https://github.com/nopnop2002). I'm using the i2s-adc lib functions to get data from an analog microphone and save it into a buffer after scaling it down to 8-bit so that the other esp32 can play it directly with its DAC converter.

At first, I had a large `i2s_read_len` and later I suspected that this could be an issue so I decided to reduce it to 12-bit (the ADC bit width of the esp32) for testing purposes. ***What is the ideal size for my audio packets?***

I'm also not sure how to handle the sampling rate of `i2s_read` and the rate at which I attempt to send data to the nRF24 via SPI. ***As far as I know the internal ADC-I2S already has a queue implemented, should I make another one and use*** `vTaskDelay(??? / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);` ***to avoid sending data too fast?***

Here's what I currently have ignoring the includes:

```
#define V_REF 1100
#define I2S_COMM_MODE 0 // ADC/DAC Mode
#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS 16
#define I2S_BUF_DEBUG 0        // enable display buffer for debug
#define I2S_READ_LEN 16 * 1024 // I2S read buffer length
#define I2S_FORMAT (I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_RIGHT)
#define I2S_CHANNEL_NUM 0              // I2S channel number
#define I2S_ADC_UNIT ADC_UNIT_1        // I2S built-in ADC unit
#define I2S_ADC_CHANNEL ADC1_CHANNEL_0 // I2S built-in ADC channel GPIO36
#define BIT_SAMPLE 16
#define SPI_DMA_CHAN SPI_DMA_CH_AUTO
#define NUM_CHANNELS 1 // For mono recording only!
#define SAMPLE_SIZE (BIT_SAMPLE * 1024)
#define BYTE_RATE (I2S_SAMPLE_RATE * (BIT_SAMPLE / 8)) * NUM_CHANNELS

/**
 * @brief I2S ADC mode init.
 */
void init_microphone(void)
{
    int i2s_num = I2S_COMM_MODE;
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_DAC_BUILT_IN | I2S_MODE_ADC_BUILT_IN,
        .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
        .bits_per_sample = I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,
        .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_MSB,
        .channel_format = I2S_FORMAT,
        .intr_alloc_flags = 0,
        .dma_buf_count = 6,
        .dma_buf_len = 256,
        .use_apll = 1,
    };
    // Call driver installation function and adc pad.
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_driver_install(i2s_num, &i2s_config, 0, NULL));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_set_adc_mode(I2S_ADC_UNIT, I2S_ADC_CHANNEL));
}
/**
 * @brief Scale data to 8bit for data from ADC.
 *        Data from ADC are 12bit width by default.
 * @param d_buff: destination buffer
 * @param s_buff: source buffer
 * @param len: length of source buffer
 */
void i2s_adc_data_scale(uint8_t *d_buff, uint8_t *s_buff, uint32_t len)
{
    uint32_t j = 0;
    uint32_t dac_value = 0;
#if (EXAMPLE_I2S_SAMPLE_BITS == 16)
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {
        dac_value = ((((uint16_t)(s_buff[i + 1] & 0xf) << 8) | ((s_buff[i + 0]))));
        d_buff[j++] = 0;
        d_buff[j++] = dac_value * 256 / 4096;
    }
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 4)
    {
        dac_value = ((((uint16_t)(s_buff[i + 3] & 0xf) << 8) | ((s_buff[i + 2]))));
        d_buff[j++] = 0;
        d_buff[j++] = 0;
        d_buff[j++] = 0;
        d_buff[j++] = dac_value * 256 / 4096;
    }
#endif
}
#if CONFIG_TRANSMITTER
void transmitter(void *pvParameters)
{
    size_t bytes_read;
    ESP_LOGI(pcTaskGetName(0), "Start");
    int i2s_read_len = (12);
    char *i2s_read_buff = (char *)calloc(i2s_read_len, sizeof(char));
    uint8_t *i2s_write_buff = (uint8_t *)calloc(i2s_read_len, sizeof(char));
    i2s_adc_enable(I2S_CHANNEL_NUM);
    NRF24_t dev;
    Nrf24_init(&dev);
    uint8_t payload = sizeof(i2s_read_buff);
    uint8_t channel = 90;
    Nrf24_config(&dev, channel, payload);
    // Set the receiver address using 5 characters
    esp_err_t ret = Nrf24_setTADDR(&dev, (uint8_t *)"FGHIJ");
    if (ret != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(pcTaskGetName(0), "nrf24l01 not installed");
        while (1)
        {
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }
    }

#if CONFIG_ADVANCED
    AdvancedSettings(&dev);
#endif // CONFIG_ADVANCED

    // Print settings
    Nrf24_printDetails(&dev);
    // Start ADC
    while (1)
    {
        // Read data from I2S bus, in this case, from ADC. //
        i2s_read(I2S_CHANNEL_NUM, (void *)i2s_read_buff, i2s_read_len, &bytes_read, portMAX_DELAY);
        // process data and scale to 8bit for I2S DAC.
        i2s_adc_data_scale(i2s_write_buff, (uint8_t *)i2s_read_buff, i2s_read_len);
        // i2s_write_buff needs to be the buffer that is sent via nr24l01.
        Nrf24_send(&dev, i2s_write_buff);

        if (Nrf24_isSend(&dev, 1000))
        {
            ESP_LOGI(pcTaskGetName(0), "sending audio data ...");
        }
        else
        {
            ESP_LOGW(pcTaskGetName(0), "sending failed ...");
        }
    }
}
#endif // CONFIG_TRANSMITTER

void app_main(void)
{
    // I2S ADC mode microphone init.
    init_microphone();
#if CONFIG_TRANSMITTER
    xTaskCreate(transmitter, "TRANSMITTER", 1024 * 3, NULL, 2, NULL);
#endif
    // Stop I2S driver and destroy
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_COMM_MODE));
}
```

Here is the code where `Nrf24_send` is defined:

```
#include <string.h>

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#include <driver/spi_master.h>
#include <driver/gpio.h>
#include "esp_log.h"

#include "mirf.h"

#define TAG "NRF24"

// SPI Stuff
#if CONFIG_SPI2_HOST
#define HOST_ID SPI2_HOST
#elif CONFIG_SPI3_HOST
#define HOST_ID SPI3_HOST
#endif

static const int SPI_Frequency = 4000000; // Stable even with a long jumper cable
//static const int SPI_Frequency = 6000000;
//static const int SPI_Frequency = 8000000; // Requires a short jumper cable
//static const int SPI_Frequency = 10000000; // Unstable even with a short jumper cable

const char rf24_datarates[][8] = {"1Mbps", "2Mbps", "250Kbps"};
const char rf24_crclength[][10] = {"Disabled", "8 bits", "16 bits"};
const char rf24_pa_dbm[][8] = {"PA_MIN", "PA_LOW", "PA_HIGH", "PA_MAX"};

void Nrf24_init(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    esp_err_t ret;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CONFIG_MISO_GPIO=%d", CONFIG_MISO_GPIO);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CONFIG_MOSI_GPIO=%d", CONFIG_MOSI_GPIO);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CONFIG_SCLK_GPIO=%d", CONFIG_SCLK_GPIO);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CONFIG_CE_GPIO=%d", CONFIG_CE_GPIO);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CONFIG_CSN_GPIO=%d", CONFIG_CSN_GPIO);

    //gpio_pad_select_gpio(CONFIG_CE_GPIO);
    gpio_reset_pin(CONFIG_CE_GPIO);
    gpio_set_direction(CONFIG_CE_GPIO, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_level(CONFIG_CE_GPIO, 0);

    //gpio_pad_select_gpio(CONFIG_CSN_GPIO);
    gpio_reset_pin(CONFIG_CSN_GPIO);
    gpio_set_direction(CONFIG_CSN_GPIO, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_level(CONFIG_CSN_GPIO, 1);

    spi_bus_config_t spi_bus_config = {
        .sclk_io_num = CONFIG_SCLK_GPIO,
        .mosi_io_num = CONFIG_MOSI_GPIO,
        .miso_io_num = CONFIG_MISO_GPIO,
        .quadwp_io_num = -1,
        .quadhd_io_num = -1
    };

    ret = spi_bus_initialize( HOST_ID, &spi_bus_config, SPI_DMA_CH_AUTO );
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "spi_bus_initialize=%d",ret);
    assert(ret==ESP_OK);

    spi_device_interface_config_t devcfg;
    memset( &devcfg, 0, sizeof( spi_device_interface_config_t ) );
    devcfg.clock_speed_hz = SPI_Frequency;
    // It does not work with hardware CS control.
    //devcfg.spics_io_num = csn_pin;
    // It does work with software CS control.
    devcfg.spics_io_num = -1;
    devcfg.queue_size = 7;
    devcfg.mode = 0;
    devcfg.flags = SPI_DEVICE_NO_DUMMY;

    spi_device_handle_t handle;
    ret = spi_bus_add_device( HOST_ID, &devcfg, &handle);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "spi_bus_add_device=%d",ret);
    assert(ret==ESP_OK);

    dev->cePin = CONFIG_CE_GPIO;
    dev->csnPin = CONFIG_CSN_GPIO;
    dev->channel = 1;
    dev->payload = 16;
    dev->_SPIHandle = handle;
}


bool spi_write_byte(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t* Dataout, size_t DataLength )
{
    spi_transaction_t SPITransaction;

    if ( DataLength > 0 ) {
        memset( &SPITransaction, 0, sizeof( spi_transaction_t ) );
        SPITransaction.length = DataLength * 8;
        SPITransaction.tx_buffer = Dataout;
        SPITransaction.rx_buffer = NULL;
        spi_device_transmit( dev->_SPIHandle, &SPITransaction );
    }

    return true;
}

bool spi_read_byte(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t* Datain, uint8_t* Dataout, size_t DataLength )
{
    spi_transaction_t SPITransaction;

    if ( DataLength > 0 ) {
        memset( &SPITransaction, 0, sizeof( spi_transaction_t ) );
        SPITransaction.length = DataLength * 8;
        SPITransaction.tx_buffer = Dataout;
        SPITransaction.rx_buffer = Datain;
        spi_device_transmit( dev->_SPIHandle, &SPITransaction );
    }

    return true;
}

uint8_t spi_transfer(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t address) {
    uint8_t datain[1];
    uint8_t dataout[1];
    dataout[0] = address;
    //spi_write_byte(dev, dataout, 1 );
    spi_read_byte(dev, datain, dataout, 1 );
    return datain[0];
}

void spi_csnHi(NRF24_t * dev) {
    gpio_set_level( dev->csnPin, 1 );
}

void spi_csnLow(NRF24_t * dev) {
    gpio_set_level( dev->csnPin, 0 );
}

// Sets the important registers in the MiRF module and powers the module
// in receiving mode
// NB: channel and payload must be set now.
void Nrf24_config(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t channel, uint8_t payload)
{
    dev->channel = channel;
    dev->payload = payload;
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_CH, dev->channel); // Set RF channel
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P0, dev->payload); // Set length of incoming payload
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P1, dev->payload);
    Nrf24_powerUpRx(dev); // Start receiver
    Nrf24_flushRx(dev);
}

// Sets the receiving device address
//void Nrf24_setRADDR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * adr)
esp_err_t Nrf24_setRADDR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * adr)
{
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_OK;
    Nrf24_writeRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P1, adr, mirf_ADDR_LEN);
    uint8_t buffer[5];
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "adr[%d]=0x%x buffer[%d]=0x%x", i, adr[i], i, buffer[i]);
        if (adr[i] != buffer[i]) ret = ESP_FAIL;
    }
    return ret;
}

// Sets the transmitting device  address
//void Nrf24_setTADDR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * adr)
esp_err_t Nrf24_setTADDR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * adr)
{
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_OK;
    Nrf24_writeRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P0, adr, mirf_ADDR_LEN); //RX_ADDR_P0 must be set to the sending addr for auto ack to work.
    Nrf24_writeRegister(dev, TX_ADDR, adr, mirf_ADDR_LEN);
    uint8_t buffer[5];
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "adr[%d]=0x%x buffer[%d]=0x%x", i, adr[i], i, buffer[i]);
        if (adr[i] != buffer[i]) ret = ESP_FAIL;
    }
    return ret;
}

// Add the receiving device address
void Nrf24_addRADDR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t pipe, uint8_t adr)
{
    uint8_t value;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, EN_RXADDR, &value, 1);

    if (pipe == 2) {
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P2, dev->payload);
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P2, adr);
        value = value | 0x04;
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, EN_RXADDR, value);
    } else if (pipe == 3) {
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P3, dev->payload);
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P3, adr);
        value = value | 0x08;
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, EN_RXADDR, value);
    } else if (pipe == 4) {
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P4, dev->payload);
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P4, adr);
        value = value | 0x10;
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, EN_RXADDR, value);
    } else if (pipe == 5) {
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_PW_P5, dev->payload);
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RX_ADDR_P5, adr);
        value = value | 0x20;
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, EN_RXADDR, value);
    }
}

// Checks if data is available for reading
extern bool Nrf24_dataReady(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    // See note in getData() function - just checking RX_DR isn't good enough
    uint8_t status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
    if ( status & (1 << RX_DR) ) return 1;
    // We can short circuit on RX_DR, but if it's not set, we still need
    // to check the FIFO for any pending packets
    //return !Nrf24_rxFifoEmpty(dev);
    return 0;
}

// Get pipe number for reading
uint8_t Nrf24_getDataPipe(NRF24_t * dev) {
    uint8_t status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
    return ((status & 0x0E) >> 1);
}

extern bool Nrf24_rxFifoEmpty(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    uint8_t fifoStatus;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, FIFO_STATUS, &fifoStatus, sizeof(fifoStatus));
    return (fifoStatus & (1 << RX_EMPTY));
}

// Reads payload bytes into data array
extern void Nrf24_getData(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * data)
{
    spi_csnLow(dev); // Pull down chip select
    spi_transfer(dev, R_RX_PAYLOAD ); // Send cmd to read rx payload
    spi_read_byte(dev, data, data, dev->payload); // Read payload
    spi_csnHi(dev); // Pull up chip select
    // NVI: per product spec, p 67, note c:
    // "The RX_DR IRQ is asserted by a new packet arrival event. The procedure
    // for handling this interrupt should be: 1) read payload through SPI,
    // 2) clear RX_DR IRQ, 3) read FIFO_STATUS to check if there are more
    // payloads available in RX FIFO, 4) if there are more data in RX FIFO,
    // repeat from step 1)."
    // So if we're going to clear RX_DR here, we need to check the RX FIFO
    // in the dataReady() function
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, STATUS, (1 << RX_DR)); // Reset status register
}

// Clocks only one byte into the given MiRF register
void Nrf24_configRegister(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t reg, uint8_t value)
{
    spi_csnLow(dev);
    spi_transfer(dev, W_REGISTER | (REGISTER_MASK & reg));
    spi_transfer(dev, value);
    spi_csnHi(dev);
}

// Reads an array of bytes from the given start position in the MiRF registers
void Nrf24_readRegister(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t reg, uint8_t * value, uint8_t len)
{
    spi_csnLow(dev);
    spi_transfer(dev, R_REGISTER | (REGISTER_MASK & reg));
    spi_read_byte(dev, value, value, len);
    spi_csnHi(dev);
}

// Writes an array of bytes into inte the MiRF registers
void Nrf24_writeRegister(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t reg, uint8_t * value, uint8_t len)
{
    spi_csnLow(dev);
    spi_transfer(dev, W_REGISTER | (REGISTER_MASK & reg));
    spi_write_byte(dev, value, len);
    spi_csnHi(dev);
}

// Sends a data package to the default address. Be sure to send the correct
// amount of bytes as configured as payload on the receiver.
void Nrf24_send(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t * value)
{
    uint8_t status;
    status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
    while (dev->PTX) // Wait until last paket is send
    {
        status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
        if ((status & ((1 << TX_DS)  | (1 << MAX_RT))))
        {
            dev->PTX = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    Nrf24_ceLow(dev);
    Nrf24_powerUpTx(dev); // Set to transmitter mode , Power up
    spi_csnLow(dev); // Pull down chip select
    spi_transfer(dev, FLUSH_TX ); // Write cmd to flush tx fifo
    spi_csnHi(dev); // Pull up chip select
    spi_csnLow(dev); // Pull down chip select
    spi_transfer(dev, W_TX_PAYLOAD ); // Write cmd to write payload
    spi_write_byte(dev, value, dev->payload); // Write payload
    spi_csnHi(dev); // Pull up chip select
    Nrf24_ceHi(dev); // Start transmission
}

// Test if chip is still sending.
// When sending has finished return chip to listening.
bool Nrf24_isSending(NRF24_t * dev) {
    uint8_t status;
    if (dev->PTX)
    {
        status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
        if ((status & ((1 << TX_DS)  | (1 << MAX_RT)))) {// if sending successful (TX_DS) or max retries exceded (MAX_RT).
            Nrf24_powerUpRx(dev);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Test if Sending has finished or retry is over.
// When sending has finished return trur.
// When reach maximum number of TX retries return false.
bool Nrf24_isSend(NRF24_t * dev, int timeout) {
    uint8_t status;
    TickType_t startTick = xTaskGetTickCount();
    if (dev->PTX) {
        while(1) {
            status = Nrf24_getStatus(dev);
            /*
                if sending successful (TX_DS) or max retries exceded (MAX_RT).
            */

            if (status & (1 << TX_DS)) { // Data Sent TX FIFO interrup
                Nrf24_powerUpRx(dev);
                return true;
            }

            if (status & (1 << MAX_RT)) { // Maximum number of TX retries interrupt
                ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Maximum number of TX retries interrupt");
                Nrf24_powerUpRx(dev);
                return false;
            }

            // I believe either TX_DS or MAX_RT will always be notified.
            // Therefore, it is unusual for neither to be notified for a period of time.
            // I don't know exactly how to respond.
            TickType_t diffTick = xTaskGetTickCount() - startTick;
            if ( (diffTick * portTICK_PERIOD_MS) > timeout) {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Status register timeout. status=0x%x", status);
                return false;
            }
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}


uint8_t Nrf24_getStatus(NRF24_t * dev) {
    uint8_t rv;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, STATUS, &rv, 1);
    return rv;
}

void Nrf24_powerUpRx(NRF24_t * dev) {
    dev->PTX = 0;
    Nrf24_ceLow(dev);
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, CONFIG, mirf_CONFIG | ( (1 << PWR_UP) | (1 << PRIM_RX) ) ); //set device as TX mode
    Nrf24_ceHi(dev);
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, STATUS, (1 << TX_DS) | (1 << MAX_RT)); //Clear seeded interrupt and max tx number interrupt
}

void Nrf24_flushRx(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    spi_csnLow(dev);
    spi_transfer(dev, FLUSH_RX );
    spi_csnHi(dev);
}

void Nrf24_powerUpTx(NRF24_t * dev) {
    dev->PTX = 1;
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, CONFIG, mirf_CONFIG | ( (1 << PWR_UP) | (0 << PRIM_RX) ) );
}

void Nrf24_ceHi(NRF24_t * dev) {
    gpio_set_level( dev->cePin, 1 );
}

void Nrf24_ceLow(NRF24_t * dev) {
    gpio_set_level( dev->cePin, 0 );
}

void Nrf24_powerDown(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    Nrf24_ceLow(dev);
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, CONFIG, mirf_CONFIG );
}

//Set tx power : 0=-18dBm,1=-12dBm,2=-6dBm,3=0dBm
void Nrf24_SetOutputRF_PWR(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t val)
{
    if (val > 3) return;

    uint8_t value;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, &value, 1);
    value = value & 0xF9;
    value = value | (val<< RF_PWR);
    //Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP,   (val<< RF_PWR) );
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, value);
}

//Select between the high speed data rates:0=1Mbps, 1=2Mbps, 2=250Kbps
void Nrf24_SetSpeedDataRates(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t val)
{
    if (val > 2) return;

    uint8_t value;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, &value, 1);
    if(val == 2)
    {
        value = value | 0x20;
        value = value & 0xF7;
        //Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP,   (1 << RF_DR_LOW) );
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, value);
    }
    else
    {
        value = value & 0xD7;
        value = value | (val << RF_DR_HIGH);
        //Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP,   (val << RF_DR_HIGH) );
        Nrf24_configRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, value);
    }
} 

//Set Auto Retransmit Delay 0=250us, 1=500us, ... 15=4000us
void Nrf24_setRetransmitDelay(NRF24_t * dev, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t value;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, SETUP_RETR, &value, 1);
    value = value & 0x0F;
    value = value | (val << ARD);
    Nrf24_configRegister(dev, SETUP_RETR, value);
}


void Nrf24_printDetails(NRF24_t * dev)
{

    printf("================ SPI Configuration ================\n" );
    printf("CSN Pin  \t = GPIO%d\n",dev->csnPin);
    printf("CE Pin  \t = GPIO%d\n", dev->cePin);
    printf("Clock Speed\t = %d\n", SPI_Frequency);
    printf("================ NRF Configuration ================\n");

    Nrf24_print_status(Nrf24_getStatus(dev));

    Nrf24_print_address_register(dev, "RX_ADDR_P0-1", RX_ADDR_P0, 2);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "RX_ADDR_P2-5", RX_ADDR_P2, 4);
    Nrf24_print_address_register(dev, "TX_ADDR\t", TX_ADDR, 1);

    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "RX_PW_P0-6", RX_PW_P0, 6);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "EN_AA\t", EN_AA, 1);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "EN_RXADDR", EN_RXADDR, 1);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "RF_CH\t", RF_CH, 1);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "RF_SETUP", RF_SETUP, 1);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "CONFIG\t", CONFIG, 1);
    Nrf24_print_byte_register(dev, "DYNPD/FEATURE", DYNPD, 2);
    //printf("getDataRate()=%d\n",Nrf24_getDataRate(dev));
    printf("Data Rate\t = %s\n",rf24_datarates[Nrf24_getDataRate(dev)]);
#if 0
    printf_P(PSTR("Model\t\t = "
    PRIPSTR
    "\r\n"),pgm_read_ptr(&rf24_model_e_str_P[isPVariant()]));
#endif
    //printf("getCRCLength()=%d\n",Nrf24_getCRCLength(dev));
    printf("CRC Length\t = %s\n", rf24_crclength[Nrf24_getCRCLength(dev)]);
    //printf("getPALevel()=%d\n",Nrf24_getPALevel(dev));
    printf("PA Power\t = %s\n", rf24_pa_dbm[Nrf24_getPALevel(dev)]);
    uint8_t retransmit = Nrf24_getRetransmitDelay(dev);
    int16_t delay = (retransmit+1)*250;
    printf("Retransmit\t = %d us\n", delay);
}

#define _BV(x) (1<<(x))

void Nrf24_print_status(uint8_t status)
{
    printf("STATUS\t\t = 0x%02x RX_DR=%x TX_DS=%x MAX_RT=%x RX_P_NO=%x TX_FULL=%x\r\n", status, (status & _BV(RX_DR)) ? 1 : 0,
            (status & _BV(TX_DS)) ? 1 : 0, (status & _BV(MAX_RT)) ? 1 : 0, ((status >> RX_P_NO) & 0x07), (status & _BV(TX_FULL)) ? 1 : 0);
}

void Nrf24_print_address_register(NRF24_t * dev, const char* name, uint8_t reg, uint8_t qty)
{
    printf("%s\t =",name);
    while (qty--) {
        //uint8_t buffer[addr_width];
        uint8_t buffer[5];
        Nrf24_readRegister(dev, reg++, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        printf(" 0x");
#if 0
        uint8_t* bufptr = buffer + sizeof buffer;
        while (--bufptr >= buffer) {
            printf("%02x", *bufptr);
        }
#endif
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\r\n");
}

void Nrf24_print_byte_register(NRF24_t * dev, const char* name, uint8_t reg, uint8_t qty)
{
    printf("%s\t =", name);
    while (qty--) {
        uint8_t buffer[1];
        Nrf24_readRegister(dev, reg++, buffer, 1);
        printf(" 0x%02x", buffer[0]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");
}

uint8_t Nrf24_getDataRate(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    rf24_datarate_e result;
    uint8_t dr;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, &dr, sizeof(dr));
    //printf("RF_SETUP=%x\n",dr);
    dr = dr & (_BV(RF_DR_LOW) | _BV(RF_DR_HIGH));

    // switch uses RAM (evil!)
    // Order matters in our case below
    if (dr == _BV(RF_DR_LOW)) {
        // '10' = 250KBPS
        result = RF24_250KBPS;
    } else if (dr == _BV(RF_DR_HIGH)) {
        // '01' = 2MBPS
        result = RF24_2MBPS;
    } else {
        // '00' = 1MBPS
        result = RF24_1MBPS;
    }
    return result;
}

uint8_t Nrf24_getCRCLength(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    rf24_crclength_e result = RF24_CRC_DISABLED;

    uint8_t config;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, CONFIG, &config, sizeof(config));
    //printf("CONFIG=%x\n",config);
    config = config & (_BV(CRCO) | _BV(EN_CRC));
    uint8_t AA;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, EN_AA, &AA, sizeof(AA));

    if (config & _BV(EN_CRC) || AA) {
        if (config & _BV(CRCO)) {
            result = RF24_CRC_16;
        } else {
            result = RF24_CRC_8;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

uint8_t Nrf24_getPALevel(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    uint8_t level;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, RF_SETUP, &level, sizeof(level));
    //printf("RF_SETUP=%x\n",level);
    level = (level & (_BV(RF_PWR_LOW) | _BV(RF_PWR_HIGH))) >> 1;
    return (level);
}

uint8_t Nrf24_getRetransmitDelay(NRF24_t * dev)
{
    uint8_t value;
    Nrf24_readRegister(dev, SETUP_RETR, &value, 1);
    return (value >> 4);
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
...
W (19498) NRF24: Maximum number of TX retries interrupt
W (19498) TRANSMITTER: sending failed ...
...
```

## Update: Transmission succeeds but audio is not inteligible - 02/2023

I found out that I'm using Si24R1 (Chinese clone of nRF24L01) and I'm still using the i2s-adc esp-idf lib functions to get data from an analog microphone and I need to get this I2S stream through the SPI interface between the ESP32 and the nRF24L01 breakout board clone. **Is this possible?**

I've seen some people mention on the internet that Nordic Semiconductors has nRF chips that support I2S but I would rather stick to the hardware I have available.

Here's the [link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30467/sending-i2s-signal-through-nrf24l01) I've consulted.

I've also found this [library](https://github.com/TMRh20/AutoAnalogAudio) that supports audio transmission using the nRF24L01/Si24R1 chip using the `nrf24.h` lib but it is writeen in c++ and it is not clear to me how I could integrate it into my project.

Let me know what you think the problem is or/and if you have good recommendations for learning material about this subject.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do your hardware works with a simple sender/receiver from sample codes you can find in adruino ide? If you didn't checked, have a try so you can validate the hardware is ok.

If simple sender/receiver doesn't work, check your power supply lines. Sometimes not enough current from the voltage regulator.
Add some caps on the rf24 module power-supply pins to filter some noise can also helps depending on the quality of the power supply.

./X

Comment: The hardware can send simple payloads with the nrf24 module but it doesn't work when I try to use i2s payloads.

Comment: This is sound as advice, and would be a perfectly reasonable comment on the question, but an answer is expected to answer the question, not suggest what research someone might do to answer it themselves.